# Stitching multiple images into one SL / WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

I am trying to download a number of images, of differnet sizes, then after some cropping stitch them into one single image.

I am intending to do this in code on a WP7 device

My current approach uses n Image controls and waits for their ImageOpened events to fire. Once they have all been successfully opened I create a new Image for each and stick them into a StackPanel.

In then use WriteableBitmap to create a single image from the stacked images.

This code works 40/50% of the time. The rest of the time the layout engine decides to not bother laying them out in a horizontal stack. All the images get rendered on top of each other.

Is there a way of forcing the StackPanel to do a full layout pass? I have tried combinations of Arrange and Measure on both the Images and the StackPanel.

Comment: If you remove image capturing to WritebleBitmap, images still rendered on top of each other? Please, provide some test project to test it by community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the article [WP7: Generate Live Tile Images Locally (Without The Visual Tree)](http://henry-chong.com/2011/09/wp7-generate-live-tile-images-locally-without-the-visual-tree/). I am now using Henry Chong’s approach (which includes UpdateLayout) and my photo stitching is working great.

I cannot help but be amused by the fact that the answer to my question “how the hell do I force the layout to be updated” was answered with a method called “UpdateLayout” [dev exits stage left kicking himself]